# End page background working, WP8, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I dont know if it is even possible, but is there some way how to "end" page in Windows Phone 8 app?

My problem is that i am using one delegate (to know when is my xml downloaded) on multiple pages. It works fine, but when i open one page, she initialize herself, i go on other page (trough back button) and new page initialize herself too. Everything is fine, but the previous page is still listening to the delegate and it is really big problem. So i need to get the previous page (that closed) into a same state like she was not ever opened.

I will be thankful for any advice (maybe i am thinking in wrong way now, i dont know, maybe the page just have to be de-initialize).

PS: If its necessary i will post the code, but i think it is not. :)

Okey here is some code:
In class whis is downloading XML i have delegate like this:

```
    public delegate void delDownloadCompleted();
    public static event delDownloadCompleted eventDownloadCompleted;
```

This class is downloading few different xml files depends of constructor in `run(int number)` method.

After is download complete and all information from xml are saved in my local list i call delegateCompled. `if (eventDownloadCompleted != null)
            {
                eventDownloadCompleted();
            }`

Then i have few different pages. All pages are used for display specific data from downloaded xml. So on this specific page I have method that is fired when "downloadClass" says it is complet.

```
XML_DynamicDataChat.delDownloadCompleted delegMetoda = new XML_DynamicDataChat.delDownloadCompleted(inicialiyaceListu);
XML_DynamicDataChat.eventDownloadCompleted += delegMetoda;
```

This is that "inicializaceListu" method:

```
private void inicialiyaceListu()
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                model = new datka();
                // object model is just model where i am saving all specific list of informations that i got from xml files.
                chatList9 = model.getChat(1);
                gui_listNovinky.ItemsSource = chatList9;
                gui_loadingGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            });
        }
```

All of these works fine, but when i go back (with back button) and open other specific page with other specific information from other downloaded xml, previous page is still listening for the delegate and `inicialiyaceListu()` method is still fired everytime i complete download of xml.

So i need to say previous page something like: "hey page, you are now closed! Can you shut the **** up and stop work?!?"

I think that specific delegate for each pages could solve this, but it is not correct programing way.

Comment: Without knowing the existing structure of the code it is hard to provide guidance. There are several possible ways to solve the problem.

Comment: I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it nice and easy. It is really simple solution. I just created bool variable and set it false when i go back. In inicializaceListu() i have condition if it is true. If it is true do that stuffs when false do nothing.